# Query MySQL Abbreviation

Tags: mysql

How to abbreviate my data in MySQL related company name with space as separation such as:

| Column A |
| --- |
| Le Meridin |
| Anne Brook Company |
| White Lion Economy Profit |

Sometimes one word, two words, three words, four words, or even five words.

This is my expectation.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Le Meridin | LM |
| Anne Brook Company | ABC |
| White Lion Economy Profit | WLEP |

Thank you.

Comment: I don’t recommend doing this in SQL. SQL is the second-worst language for text-processing next to `awk`